# Tiling System C++ SDL

Tags: c++, sdl

I have been working on a tiling system for a video game I've been designing through C++ and SDL. The code is loosely based off of the tutorials available on lazyfoo.net, but with a different system to draw the tiles to the screen. The code works as follows: I have a class called `Map` that creates an array of another class called `Tile`. It also has a function called `set_tiles` that reads numbers from a .map file and copies them to the array of `tile`'s using two for loops; one for the x's and one for the y's. I then blit each surface to a temporary map according to the `Tile`'s specific variables. Here is the actual code:

## Map.cpp

```
SDL_Surface* Map::set_tiles ( SDL_Surface* tile_image ) {
Setup setup;

SDL_Surface* temp_map = NULL;

//Open the map
std::ifstream map ( "Test.map" );

//Catch any errors
if ( map.fail() ) return NULL;

//Initialize the tiles
for ( int y = 0; y < MAP_HEIGHT / TILE_HEIGHT; y++ ) {
    for ( int x = 0; x < MAP_WIDTH / TILE_WIDTH; x++ ) {
        //Determines the tile type
        int tile_type = -1;

        //Read the tile type from the map
        map >> tile_type;

        //Make sure it's a real tile
        if ( tile_type < 0 || tile_type >= TILE_SPRITES ) {
            map.close();
            return NULL;
        }

        //Error check for the .map file
        if ( map.fail() ) {
            map.close();
            return NULL;
        }

        //Add the tile to the array
        tile_array[x][y] = &Tile ( x, y, tile_type );

        //Create the temp. image crop
        SDL_Rect* temp_crop = &tile_array[x][y]->get_crop();

        //Check for crop errors
        if ( ( temp_crop->h || temp_crop->w ) == 0 ) return NULL;

        //Edit the temp. map
        setup.apply_surface ( x * TILE_WIDTH, y * TILE_HEIGHT, tile_image, temp_map, temp_crop );
    }
}

map.close();

//Return the modified map
return temp_map;
```

}

## Tile.cpp

```
Tile::Tile ( int x, int y, int tile_type ) {
//Get the offsets
box.x = x;
box.y = y;

//Set the collision box
box.w = TILE_WIDTH;
box.h = TILE_HEIGHT;

//Get the tile type
type = tile_type;

//Choose the crop option
crop.w = TILE_WIDTH;
crop.h = TILE_HEIGHT;

switch ( tile_type ) {
case TILE_RED:
    crop.x = 0 * TILE_WIDTH;
    crop.y = 0 * TILE_HEIGHT;
    break;
case TILE_GREEN:
    crop.x = 1 * TILE_WIDTH;
    crop.y = 0 * TILE_HEIGHT;
    break;
case TILE_BLUE:
    crop.x = 2 * TILE_WIDTH;
    crop.y = 0 * TILE_HEIGHT;
    break;
case TILE_CENTER:
    crop.x = 3 * TILE_WIDTH;
    crop.y = 0 * TILE_HEIGHT;
    break;
case TILE_TOP:
    crop.x = 0 * TILE_WIDTH;
    crop.y = 1 * TILE_HEIGHT;
    break;
case TILE_TOPRIGHT:
    crop.x = 1 * TILE_WIDTH;
    crop.y = 1 * TILE_HEIGHT;
    break;
case TILE_RIGHT:
    crop.x = 2 * TILE_WIDTH;
    crop.y = 1 * TILE_HEIGHT;
    break;
case TILE_BOTTOMRIGHT:
    crop.x = 3 * TILE_WIDTH;
    crop.y = 1 * TILE_HEIGHT;
    break;
case TILE_BOTTOM:
    crop.x = 0 * TILE_WIDTH;
    crop.y = 2 * TILE_HEIGHT;
    break;
case TILE_BOTTOMLEFT:
    crop.x = 1 * TILE_WIDTH;
    crop.y = 2 * TILE_HEIGHT;
    break;
case TILE_LEFT:
    crop.x = 2 * TILE_WIDTH;
    crop.y = 2 * TILE_HEIGHT;
    break;
case TILE_TOPLEFT:
    crop.x = 3 * TILE_WIDTH;
    crop.y = 2 * TILE_HEIGHT;
    break;
}
```

}

The problem is that `set_tiles` returns a NULL pointer when it is called. Through a bit of debugging I found that it makes it all the way to the end and then returns a NULL, it doesn't do it somewhere in the for loops. I've also tried setting all `tile` crop.x's and y's to 0, just to see if it would work, but it doesn't.

**NOTICE**
The problem is not my image or the .map file.
I think that my understanding of pointers may be a bit faulty, and that I may have made a mistake when calling `apply_surface`.

## Setup.cpp

```
void Setup::apply_surface ( int x, int y, SDL_Surface* source, SDL_Surface* &destination, SDL_Rect* clip ) {
//Temporary rectangle to hold the offsets
SDL_Rect offset;

//Get the offsets
offset.x = x;
offset.y = y;

//Blit the surface
SDL_BlitSurface ( source, clip, destination, &offset );
```

}

Comment: Where is the `Setup` class defined?  Unless the `apply_surface` function takes a reference to an SDL_Surface pointer as its 4th parameter (that is, `SDL_Surface*&`), there is nothing in this function that changes `temp_map` from its initialization as a NULL pointer.

Comment: Googling "apply_surface" leads me to [this](http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson06/index.php), but in that case, it's not a member of a class.  If that's where you got the code from, and just encapsulated it in a class called `Setup` without changing the parameter types, then yes, you are making a mistake in calling `apply_surface`.

Comment: Good Google fu - I removed my answer.  I had assumed incorrectly about some stuff.

Comment: What are you suggesting I do, Ben? I don't really even understand your complaint to be honest. I have another class called `Hero` with a function that prints the hero to the screen just fine.

Comment: I'm asking you to present the `Setup` class, because I don't know what it is.  It's not part of SDL.

Comment: Edited my code to include the setup class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SDL_BlitSurface` blits one surface to another.  They both must be initialized, otherwise the function does nothing.  You are passing a NULL pointer to it.  You need to initialize the pointer with a call to something like [SDL_CreateRGBSurface](http://wiki.libsdl.org/moin.cgi/SDL_CreateRGBSurface).

Comment: That makes perfect sense. I did a bit of research and found out how to use `SDL_CreateRGBSurface`. It is no longer returning a NULL. However, it is still not returning the image that I want. There must be another problem somewhere.

Comment: @JimHurley: I don't doubt that, but one problem per post please.