# SDL Tiling part 2

Tags: c++, sdl

I earlier posted a problem in SDL complaining that my function would always return a null. I got an answer to my problem that definitely solved something, but not everything. This is the post: [Tiling System C++ SDL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14918149/tiling-system-c-sdl/14918349#comment20930290_14918349)

I added the following to my `map.cpp` file:

```
//Make a temporary map to draw the tiles to
Uint32 rmask, gmask, bmask, amask;
if ( SDL_BYTEORDER == SDL_BIG_ENDIAN ) {
    rmask = 0xff000000;
    gmask = 0x00ff0000;
    bmask = 0x0000ff00;
    amask = 0x000000ff;
}
else {
    rmask = 0x000000ff;
    gmask = 0x0000ff00;
    bmask = 0x00ff0000;
    amask = 0xff000000;
}
SDL_Surface* temp_map = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(SDL_SWSURFACE, MAP_WIDTH, MAP_HEIGHT, 32, rmask, gmask, bmask, amask);
```

Although the image no longer returns null, my function still does not print the tiles onto the image at all. The image remains completely transparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should generate a valid `test_map`, see `SDL_CreateRGBSurface` documented [here](http://www.libsdl.org/docs/html/sdlcreatergbsurface.html).

One thing to keep in mind is that your `SDL_Rect` in `apply_surface` does not have all of its values set. `SDL_Rect` does not have a default constructor zeroing the memory. You only assign the `x` and `y` but never the `w` and `h`, which means that your `w` and `h` will contain garbage. You should initialize these values to your source surface's `w` and `h` as suggested in [this example](http://www710.univ-lyon1.fr/~jciehl/Public/SDL_PG/guidevideoexamples.html).

Comment: Thank you for the help, I had figured it out myself but it wouldn't let me answer my own question for another few hours and by that time I had forgotten. And thanks for the advice!